# Make header sticky on scroll wihtout fixed position?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying have my header stick on scroll. The is a fixed with, 1160px and is located below another div, and I want it stuck at top on scroll. Problem is I cant do it with a fixed position.

Seems like every script solution requires it to be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide a code, fiddle or anything ?

Comment: Because `fixed` position is relative to the screen... so you want it in `absolute`?

Comment: the usernames>>> Xlander & Xeptor

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you could try `position: sticky`.

```
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/xJaxoP

Browser support for position sticky: https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20sticky